# Java Jax-RS (Jersey) Backend & jQuery Frontend -> Security + Session

Tags: jquery, authentication, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I am currently developing a lightweight web application using Jax-RS on the server side (deployed on a tomcat 7 container) and HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery in the frontend.

The connection works fine. What I don't know is how to secure the application. My idea is that a user may register through the frontend and is assigned to a default role (e.g. users).

From then on, the user may login to the website and is able to e.g. register for a course or something like that.

How can achieve this on a secure way? Is it best to use tomcats authentication (DIGEST or FORM)? Or is there another way? Like e.g. transmitting user & password as MD5 hash in every request?

It would be great if I could use @RolesAllowed Annotation in Ressource Class to annotate methods which should only be accessible for specific groups.

And how can I store the user-data on the client? So that the user doesnt needs to sign in after every request? Do I have to use cookies for that?

Another thing I'm not sure is how to store data from a shopping cart. Would it be a good idea to use a DB table on the server where I store all the shopping cart contents for a specific user? How do I have to identify the user there? How would the mapping between logged-in user and shopping-cart entry in table look like?

I hope that someone can help me :-).

Thanks in advance

Greets

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in several systems using the session cookie. The simple way is to add `@Context HttpServletRequest` as a parameter on every server-side Jersey-fied method, and it will be there to grab the session from. In my case I have a security handler (similar to Shiro, but without its baggage) that places a wrapped user session in the thread context as a Tomcat filter, so I don't use the `@Context HttpServletRequest` annotation. Should a user try to access a restful resource by ID that is not available to them, they get no response.

Answer (score 0):

I would use FORM authentication as you suggest yourself. You could generate the context security constraints by using the role annotations.

To store user information like a basket, save it in a session object, and then serialize to disk or database on expiry for further persistency.